# tns appstore upload: Unable to connect to iTunes Connect (1268)

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

## Unable to upload .ipa file using NativeScript cmd

### I'm running the following command:

`tns appstore upload my-appstore-id my-appstore-pass --ipa /var/www/app.ipa`

### See the following error message:

`Unable to connect to iTunes Connect
An error occurred while processing the json request. (1268)`

no other messages or logs are provided.

Have no idea where to search for solution.

Comment: Same problem here - started happening yesterday

Comment: any solution to this? same issue here. is password supposed to be app-specific password? or actual itunes password? @BrianDilley

Answer (score 0):

This was a known issue on the nativescript end. https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/2874

I had ran into this a few weeks ago and after upgrading to nativescript@next the issue went away.

To answer @BrianDilley you need to supply your itunes password, it's not app specific.